# Causal modeling and DAGs in Python - where to start and what are the best sources?

Tags: machine-learning, python, causality, dag

I am very new to causal models (and econometrics) and need to pick up basics fast. I am comfortable with ML though. I did an extensive research during last several days on causality, DAGs, and modeling, but still not sure how to approach it properly. Having [the same problem as this user](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/545054/causal-inference-in-python-where-to-start).

So far I have went through:

- Basics of Judea Peal and his work
- This [cool book](https://matheusfacure.github.io/) by Matheus Facure
- Several MOOCs like [UPenn Crash Course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/crash-course-in-causality) and [Brady Neal Course](https://www.bradyneal.com/causal-inference-course)
- Python libraries like [DoWhy](https://microsoft.github.io/dowhy/), [CausalNex](https://www.bradyneal.com/causal-inference-course), and others

But still I do not see enough clear examples of modeling work (or maybe I am looking in a wrong direction). I do not touch Bayesian Networks for now, this is unnecessary for this project.

What I am trying to do right now:

- I need to build a DAG and **a simple and explainable causal model** with a couple of numeric X variables only and a numeric Y variable. I think I can do it with some libraries above. But if I understand correctly, DAG is just a graphical representation of the relationship and I need a model behind.
- I googled a lot about ML, DAGs, etc, but still either do not understand it well (which is true), looking in a wrong direction). Facure's book is the closest I have seen so far about modeling and evaluation of causal models **(where to read about evaluation more?)**

I would greatly appreciate some tips - feel free to share your favorite resources!

Comment: Are you just trying to get a model to play around with? Or are you trying to model a real-world scenario? I'd imagine living on Tatooine, it might be difficult to relate to those of us here on earth. ;-)

Comment: @AdrianKeister, I was assigned to a Death Star causality project and need to build a real model, using DAG, showing the causal effect between money spent and events on the number of activities. If you can help to fight against the evil, I would greatly appreciate it :)

Comment: Ah, I see. We'd better work quickly before you turn to the Dark Side. When you get to the specifics of DAGs, you simply ask yourself, "Does this variable affect that one?" of every variable-variable pair. That's usually the easier part, though it can be highly non-trivial. Pearl's book *Causality: Models, Reasoning, and Inference* has an algorithm that can help discover DAGs based on real-world data. Getting the Structural Causal Models is harder, though. Your best bet is domain experts: ask them and see what they come up with.

Comment: @AdrianKeister, many thanks. I have this book as well his other books. But they are tough as laser sword of Darth Vader. Do I understand correctly that DAG is a visualization and I need to build a model behind, controlling for some variables. Do you have any good tips about resources? I can imagine I can build a regression model, but not sure because I do not see some intuitive tutorials. This might help, no? https://theeffectbook.net/the-toolbox.html

Comment: Yes, the DAG is a visualization, and it goes hand-in-hand with a SCM, although there are MANY things you can deduce about a system merely from its DAG. I also found Pearl's *Causality* book extremely difficult - I've only been able to force my way through a small part of it. But he has easier books that might help. I recommend reading these, in order: *The Book of Why*, and *Causal Inference in Statistics: A Primer*. That's a great link you have. Definitely might help as well.

Comment: @AdrianKeister, thanks, I am re-reading The Book of Why right now. It is a mandatory reading on Tatooine. Very intuitive. I also tried Primer. Have you seen any full stack tutorials how to go from a DAG to a model and its evaluation, ideally in Python. I have not. Only some disaggregated pieces.

Comment: Well, as I said, that link above seems good - it's at a suitable, intro level. I think I might well avail myself of it! Modeling is a highly iterative process: you try something and see how well it works. 

https://xkcd.com/1838/

I will say this: it's much easier to see if a given model is off by a lot, than to show that it works really well. You can just start with linear regression: you control for variables simply by including them on the RHS. But, as Pearl has pointed out, be careful what you control for. Avoid controlling for mediators!